# Исходник с#

Tags: c#

В Java пишется приложение - A.java. Потом JVM делает A.class. А как в C#? Какой аналог A.java у С# ?

**Дополнено.**

dir

- папка - bin (эта папка , аналог папки java? лежат скомпилированные файлы)
- папка - obj (что тут лежит?)
- папка - Properties (что за папка?)
- файл - Program.cs (тип файла : Visual C# Source file (.cs))
- файл - ConsoleApplication11 (тип файла : Visual C# Project file (.csproj))
- Program.cs - это он? (он во всех - я просто хочу отослать программу и хочу понять, что мне отсылать, не всю же папку ConsoleApplication11).

Answer (score 1):

В самом простом случае консольного приложения достаточно одного файла cs. Его можно собрать и без Visual Studio

```
csc.exe Program.cs
```

Если есть какая-то работа с настройкам, может понадобиться папка Properties, если есть изменения в файле проекта, отличные от умолчаний, может потребоваться файл проекта .csproj.

Comment: А почему когда я в Visual Studio и хочу найти файл Program.cs ( ищу через : File - Open - Project ) оболочка его не видит? А когда через обычный проводник захожу, файл Programc.cs  на месте.

Comment: Потому что студия обучена работать с проектами... читай Троелсена - там все в деталях описано...
и ИМХО делать паралели исходников джавы и щарпа не совсем хорошо...

Answer (score 0):

Расширение файла с исходным кодом C# — `.cs`. То есть в вашем случае `A.cs`.

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.